# question about simple MINA client and server

Tags: apache-mina

I am just trying to create a simple MINA server and client to evaluate. Here is my code.

```
public class Server {

private static final int PORT = 8080;

static class ServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(IoSession session) {
        System.out.println("session is created");
        session.write("Thank you");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("session is closed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {
        System.out.println("message=" + message);
        session.write("Reply="+message);
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SocketAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "logger", new LoggingFilter() );
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
    acceptor.setHandler(new Server.ServerHandler());
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize( 2048 );
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime( IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10 );
    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
    System.out.println("Listening on port " + PORT);
    for (;;) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Client {
private static final int PORT = 8080;

private IoSession session;
private ClientHandler handler;
public Client() {
    super();
}

public void initialize() throws Exception {
    handler = new ClientHandler();
    NioSocketConnector connector = new NioSocketConnector();
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
    connector.setHandler(handler);
    for (;;) {
        try {
            ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
            future.awaitUninterruptibly();
            session = future.getSession();
            break;
        } catch (RuntimeIoException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to connect.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    if (session == null) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get session");
    }
    Sender sender = new Sender();
    sender.start();

    session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    connector.dispose();
    System.out.println("client is done.");
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.initialize();
}

class Sender extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.messageSent(session, "message");
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageSent(IoSession session, Object message) {
        System.out.println("message sending=" + message);
        session.write(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {
        System.out.println("message receiving "+ message);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When I execute this code, the Client seems to keep sending a message instead of stopping after it sends. It looks to me that there is a recursive call in underlying MINA code. I know that I am doing something wrong.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize and start your `sender` and use the `session` within `sessionOpened` (ClientHandler)